Flutter cannot scroll to the bottom of the list View
can anyone tell why the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics doesn't allow to scroll to the bottom of the view if the list is more than 10+! ill share some code and the original link if anyone wants to test.
if you want to test the code please click the link bellow and test it from the android device or the web
here is the Link
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdvancedDrawer(
      backdropColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
      controller: _advancedDrawerController,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      animateChildDecoration: true,
      rtlOpening: false,
      disabledGestures: false,
      childDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade900,
            blurRadius: 20.0,
            spreadRadius: 5.0,
            offset: Offset(-20.0, 0.0),
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: ListTileTheme(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            iconColor: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 80.0,
                  height: 80.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20,
                    top: 24.0,
                  ),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/avatar-1.png')
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                  child: Text("John Doe", 
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade800,),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Iconsax.home),
                  title: Text('Dashboard'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Iconsax.chart_2),
                  title: Text('Analytics'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Iconsax.profile_2user),
                  title: Text('Contacts'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Divider(color: Colors.grey.shade800),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Iconsax.setting_2),
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Iconsax.support),
                  title: Text('Support'),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text('Version 1.0.0', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500),),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 250.0,
              elevation: 0,
              pinned: true,
              stretch: true,
              toolbarHeight: 80,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              leading: IconButton(
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
                icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
                  valueListenable: _advancedDrawerController,
                  builder: (_, value, __) {
                    return AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                      child: Icon(
                        value.visible ? Iconsax.close_square : Iconsax.menu,
                        key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Iconsax.notification, color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Iconsax.more, color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
                ),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              title: AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: _isScrolled ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '\$ 1,840.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Container(
                      width: 30,
                      height: 4,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                title: AnimatedOpacity(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  opacity: _isScrolled ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      FadeIn(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('\$', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 22),),
                            SizedBox(width: 3,),
                            Text('1,840.00',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 28,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      FadeIn(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          height: 30,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Add Money', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          elevation: 0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 3,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  height: 115,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: _services.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return FadeInDown(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: (index + 1) * 100),
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (_services[index][0] == 'Transfer') { 
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ContactPage()));
                              }
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 60,
                                  height: 60,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Icon(_services[index][1], color: Colors.white, size: 25,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                Text(_services[index][0], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 12),),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ])
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 30),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    FadeInDown(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text('Today', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text('\$ 1,840.00', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,)),
                        ]
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: _transactions.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return FadeInDown(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                    blurRadius: 5,
                                    spreadRadius: 1,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 6),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Image.network(_transactions[index][1], width: 50, height: 50,),
                                      SizedBox(width: 15,),
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(_transactions[index][0], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade900, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14),),
                                          SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                          Text(_transactions[index][2], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 12),),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Text(_transactions[index][3], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  List<dynamic> _transactions = [
    ['Amazon', 'https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/amazon.png', '6:25pm', '\$8.90'],
    ['Cash from ATM', 'https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry/2x/external-atm-banking-and-finance-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry.png', '5:50pm', '\$200.00'],
    ['Netflix', 'https://img.icons8.com/color-glass/2x/netflix.png', '2:22pm', '\$13.99'],
    ['Apple Store', 'https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/mac-os--v2.gif', '6:25pm', '\$4.99'],
    ['Cash from ATM', 'https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry/2x/external-atm-banking-and-finance-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry.png', '5:50pm', '\$200.00'],
    ['Netflix', 'https://img.icons8.com/color-glass/2x/netflix.png', '2:22pm', '\$13.99'],    ['Amazon', 'https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/amazon.png', '6:25pm', '\$8.90'],
    ['Cash from ATM', 'https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry/2x/external-atm-banking-and-finance-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry.png', '5:50pm', '\$200.00'],
    ['Netflix', 'https://img.icons8.com/color-glass/2x/netflix.png', '2:22pm', '\$13.99'],
    ['Apple Store', 'https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/mac-os--v2.gif', '6:25pm', '\$4.99'],
    ['Cash from ATM', 'https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry/2x/external-atm-banking-and-finance-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry.png', '5:50pm', '\$200.00'],
    ['Netflix', 'https://img.icons8.com/color-glass/2x/netflix.png', '2:22pm', '\$13.99'],    ['Amazon', 'https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/amazon.png', '6:25pm', '\$8.90'],
    ['Cash from ATM', 'https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry/2x/external-atm-banking-and-finance-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry.png', '5:50pm', '\$200.00'],
    ['Netflix', 'https://img.icons8.com/color-glass/2x/netflix.png', '2:22pm', '\$13.99'],
    ['Apple Store', 'https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/mac-os--v2.gif', '6:25pm', '\$4.99'],
    ['Cash from ATM', 'https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry/2x/external-atm-banking-and-finance-kiranshastry-lineal-color-kiranshastry.png', '5:50pm', '\$200.00'],
    ['Netflix', 'https://img.icons8.com/color-glass/2x/netflix.png', '2:22pm', '\$13.99']
  ];


Uhm, doesn't the name NeverScrollableScrollPhysics  already tells you why it will not scroll?

Please test the code if you have time and share your solution if you find one :) @Thomas

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html states that if you choose this Scrollphysics your scroll view will not scroll. Why do you use it at all?

i want to list all the items from ListView.builder but i dont want to have two scrollable widgets

Can you please reduce the amount of code and try to show a minimal example that shows the same behavior?
